# Laravel route prefix not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem with laravel 5 route. I have use

`Route::get('Client-View/{id}', [
    'as' => 'Client-View', 'uses' => 'ClientListController@editClient'
]);`

or too

```
Route::get('Client-View/{id}', 'ClientListController@editClient');
```

the route work fine but some Js and image not found(404) when is use `'Client-View/{id}'`. If I use only `'{id}'` that works .In case of `'Client-View/{id}'` HTTP request is `http://meghavisa.dev/Client-View/assets/js/slidebars/slidebars.min.js` but it should look like this `http://meghavisa.dev/assets/js/slidebars/slidebars.min.js`.

Controller--

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class ClientListController extends Controller {

    public function editClient($id){
        $user = User::find($id);          
        return view('admin.client-view', ['clientView'=>$user]);
    }

}
```

Please help Thank You !

Comment: Use the `asset()` helper function.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing something like

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

You should use the asset() helper function like

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

Use this function also for you image sources.

You could also try out http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html .
Then you can include your scripts and styles like: ( And aditionally you also have the Form Facade back )

```
{!! Html::script('js/script.js') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

Comment: Well, in my tests your descripbed behaviour is just the same for me, when i don't use asset() ..... Have you tried using the Html Facade from LaravelCollective ?